# What is the fastest way to start an app in Windows 8?

Tags: windows-8-preview

I use the start button a lot to launch applications e.g.

1. press start
2. type "power"
3. Enter

And PowerShell pops up. How can I map this process in Windows 8? (ideally without mouse or touch)

Comment: That is the fastest way, you move your hands less when doing that than when you would grab for the mouse and have to go find PowerShell. So, you have basically answered your own question. For your off-question, just type `Help` instead of `Power` and then click on Get Started in Help and Support... :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just because there is no Start button any longer doesn't mean you can't do it like that anymore.

You can still click the bottom left corner to bring up the *Metro Start menu* and type `power`. It works just as well.

[image]

What would be more ideal, would be to use the Windows Logo key on your keyboard (if you have one). That would also be more ideal on previous versions of Windows in my opinion.

Comment: It is going to be a huge learning curve.

Comment: In the Start screen of Windows 8 you simply start typing and it makes a search. Launching apps via search is faster than in Windows 7.

Answer (score 2):

Try the <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd> and <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> shortcuts.

Answer (score 0):

With Windows 8 a lot of functionality is still there, but has been hidden. So like there is no start button anymore, you can still access Windows 8's equivalent (Start Screen) by click in the very bottom left corner of the screen.

So in the same way you would search in windows 7, by clicking the start button and typing in the search box which is preselected for you, you can press open the Start Screen and just start typing, even though there is no search box as soon as you start typing it will appear.

Answer (score 0):

Did anyone mention right-click the Windows PowerShell icon, and Pin to Start?

Talking of PowerShell, does anyone else have trouble with the ISE version.  For me, PowerShell ISE opens into the command line version.